# Localization issue with iOS11 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I just built an app that is using localization with the code

```
let locale = NSLocale.current.languageCode
```

What it returns to me and the simulator is something like "zh" (For Traditional Chinese Users)

However, when I upload it to the App Store, other users using traditional Chinese has found that the localization is not working properly. (i.e. Not showing Chinese), but on my phone it works perfectly! For the same label and same page!

Does anyone has a similar problem on it?

The only possible solution I can think of is changing NSLocale to Locale, will it work?

p.s. All iOS device is running on 11.3

Comment: In Swift you should be using `Locale` and not `NSLocale` but that has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't depend on local to return language code , I check my localized value , for example say i support 2 languages in my app i would have

fr file

```
"currentCode" = "fr"
```

en file

```
"currentCode" = "en"
```

and while the app is opened , I check what's current language selected by system with

```
if NSLocalizedString("currentCode",comment:"") == "fr" {
    //
}
else {
   // 
}
```